# Selenium Chromedriver screenshot in Java has diffrent resolution than the one set

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I’m using **Selenium** with **Chrome driver** to take a screenshot of a site and setting the window dimension to 800x600. When I look at the .png it’s greater than that and changes per screen resolution. The difference is greater than the scroll bars, Set it to capture 800x600 and it produces a 1179x704 image(my monitor res is 3840 x 2160). This also changes per the resolution on the monitor. Is there a way to set it so the output is the same no matter what the screen resolution is?

i've tried:

driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));

&

options.addArguments("window-size=800x600");

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {   

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

    //options.addArguments("window-size=800x600");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    driver.get("https://www.website.com");
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);


        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("screenshot.png"));
        System.out.println("DONE TAKING SCREENSHOT OF SITE");
```

Comment: according to this: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/1067 the take screen shot command is not aligned with the window screen according to WebDriver spec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind switching to headless mode, try adding these lines:

```
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("--window-size=800,600");
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I found this to be true a long time ago and I forgot to update on here! Thanks again!